# kinect not detected

Tags: ros, kinect, ros-hydro, openni2, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys.

I'm using ros hydro
I read in the ros answers site that openni2 and freenect can be used with windows kinect, so i installed using `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni2-*` and installed freenect with `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-freenect-stack`

But there is a problem, the windows kinect is not detected when i type `roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch` There is a message that says `[ INFO] [1383342884.120184670]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-openni2-camera-0.1.0-0raring-20131015-2254/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 623 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.`  and this message keeps iterating

When i type `lsusb` in the console, it detects the windows kinect.

I'm a ros newbie, i have no clue what to do next. I'm doing something wrong?

I'll appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97081/kinect-not-detected/) by [Bernard_o](https://answers.ros.org/users/6446/bernard_o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-11-01

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-11-02**:
Can you see three entries in the result for ' lsusb ' command for Kinect ? Also, your kinect should be powered along with being connected to netbook/ laptop.

Also, did you try with simple install ?
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-launch  ros-hydro-openni-tracker ros-hydro-openni-camera

**Comment by [Bernard_o](https://answers.ros.org/users/6446/bernard_o/) on 2013-11-10**:
Thanks for answering .. hmm, didn't knew that kinect use 3 entries, i will check it. But, it really needs to detect the 3 entries?

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-11-25**:
Yes, the entries that come up when you use 'lsusb' command as below:

Bus 001 Device 010: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera

Did you try with above simple install ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

openni2_launch will load openni2_camera -- this package/driver does NOT support any version of the Kinect. If you are wanting to use freenect,  you should be using freenect_launch, not openni2_launch

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [olzhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/18451/olzhas/) on 2014-05-29**:
unless you install libFreenectDriver, which is a libfreenect-based driver for OpenNI2

https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/tree/master/OpenNI2-FreenectDriver

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-05-30**:
Have you actually tested that against a debian install of openni2_camera?

**Comment by [olzhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/18451/olzhas/) on 2014-05-30**:
Nope, I tested it on Ubuntu 12.04 with openni2 2.2.0.33 ([https://launchpad.net/~eighthave/+archive/openni](https://launchpad.net/%7Eeighthave/+archive/openni))
also I recompiled the openni2_* packages. and It worked.